# I need to make an small app with the the database stored in the app or on the server

Tags: iphone, sqlite

Just for the trial purpose i want to make an app for my iphone/iPad which can use a sqlite database locally or on a server. So how should i do this??? How should i get and post the data back and forth. I know its a lot to ask in a single question but if there is any link or tutorial you can provide me with, that would be great.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are pretty good tutorials available to learn about sqlite & iphone programming,
I suggest these...
http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/
http://www.mobileorchard.com/iphone-sqlite-tutorials-and-libraries/

Comment: That's great. Could you also share some links where is there more interaction with web.